# I not am getting a value outside of a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
foreach(string id in eid)
{
eventModifiedTime =(Convert.ToDateTime(lastModifiedDate.InnerXml)).ToUniversalTime();
}
callTimeUpdateQuery = gblManager.ProcessSingleQuote(InlineSQL.UpdateHistory, Convert.ToString(eventModifiedTime));
```

IN the last line I want the value from eventModifiedTime  inside the foreach how can I get that value I an getting an error on the eventModifiedTime on the last line as ==> Use of unassigned local variable 'eventModifiedTime'

Comment: Please don't add multiple language tags. Only use the tags for the language you're using.

Comment: @cigien asp.net is not a language

Comment: @FCR Yes, that's true, but the question was originally tagged with C and C++ as well, which are different languages (from each other, as well as C#).

Comment: @cigien oops, sorry then mate

Comment: Why do you have that foreach-loop? You are not using that "id" and overwrite that eventModifiedTime

Comment: Actually the code is too big so  to shorten up the code I have removed most of the code

Comment: The code doesn't make much sense - which is what the error is hinting at. If you have 5 id strings, the loop will run 5 times and eventModifiedTime will have 5 different values at different moments (once value for each time the loop runs). So which one of those values did you want to use in your call to the `ProcessSingleQuote` method? It isn't clear. Maybe you actually should be calling `ProcessSingleQuote` from _within_ the loop so it runs once for every different value of eventModifiedTime... That would probably make more sense but then again I don't know what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @ADyson Actually I want the last eventModifiedTime  which will be for the id 5

Comment: Then why do you not just pull that specific item out of the array, instead of pointlessly looping through data you're not interested in?

Answer (score 0):

The code will probably run if we force it. The problem is, from code-analysis perspective (compile time), there's no guarantee that for-each will ever have iterations (until runtime). For example, when `eid` is `Enumerable.Empty<string>`, in which case, there will be no value for `eventModifiedTime`.

To address that issue, you will need to come up with a default value for eventModifiedTime and assign it in front.

Consider this example:

```cs
// DateTime eventModifiedTime;  // Give it a default value like it below:
DateTime eventModifiedTime = DateTime.MinValue; // give it a default value. Come up with one that makes sense.
foreach(var x in Enumerable.Empty<string>())
{
    // Won't run since list is empty.
    eventModifiedTime = DateTime.Now;
}

Console.WriteLine(eventModifiedTime);
```

It is just a compiler forcing us to think through possibilities of failures.